# Increase element width by percentage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, percentage

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134997) by [Varinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497815/varinder) works well but I would like to get the element width which is set in pixels and increase it by 10%.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".ml").each(function() { // this is kindof sugary way of doing for loop over array of elements - which is $(".ml")
         var $this = $(this); // the current jQueried .ml element
         var currentWidth = $this.width(); // get width of current element, width is a jQuery method: https://api.jquery.com/width/
         var newWidth = currentWidth + 5; // increment the width
         $this.width(newWidth); // pass in the new width as the parameter.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's several ways to do that, try ;

```
 var currentWidth = $this.width();

 var newWidth = currentWidth * 1.1; //increment by 10%
 //OR
 var newWidth = currentWidth + ( currentWidth * 10) / 100; //increment by 10%
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the currentWidth with `var newWidth = currentWidth * 1.1;`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the new width to the old width + 10% of the old width:

```
var newWidth = currentWidth + (currentWidth * 0.1);
```